# SQL Server SPID returns after being killed

Tags: sql-server

I have a SPID in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database that shouldn't be there. It was created on a copy database job and that database and job have long since been deleted.

The SPID however did not disappear and tries to reconnect to my database every 1 minute and is filling up my error log.

I tried using the `KILL ##` command where ## is the process id but it just comes back with a new session id.

I have restarted the server made sure all possibly associated jobs are completed.

Does anybody know how I can end this SPID for good?

When it tries to run every minute it gives me this error message in my logs:

```
Log Name:      Application   
Source:        MSSQLSERVER  
Date:          1/2/2013 11:34:24 AM  
Event ID:      18456  
Task Category: Logon  
Level:         Information  
Keywords:      Classic,Audit Failure  
User:          DOMAIN\userid  
Computer:      server.domain.com  
Description:  
Login failed for user 'domain\userid. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. CLIENT: <local machine>]  
Event Xml:  
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">  
  <System>  
    <Provider Name="MSSQLSERVER" />  
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">18456</EventID>  
    <Level>0</Level>  
    <Task>4</Task>  
    <Keywords>0x90000000000000</Keywords>  
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-01-02T19:34:24.000000000Z" />  
    <EventRecordID>19934006</EventRecordID>  
    <Channel>Application</Channel>  
    <Computer>server.domain.com</Computer>  
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-3027188495-1942244818-4144419180-3136" />  
  </System>  
  <EventData>  
    <Data>DOMAIN\userid</Data>  
    <Data> Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database.</Data>  
    <Data> [CLIENT: &lt;local machine&gt;]</Data>  
      <Binary>184800000E00000006000000410043004500500034000000070000006D00610073007400650072000000</Binary>  
  </EventData>  
</Event>
```

Comment: Can you share the most recent information from the errorlog file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you have an external (external to SQL Server) process trying to connect to SQL Server.  The login fails because the process can't connect to the database, which I suspect has already been deleted.  This process continues to retry to connect to the SQL Server.  You can't kill the SPID, because the external process is designed to reconnect.

The process is associated with the copy database job.  Did you create the copy-database job by right clicking the source database in the SSMS Object Manager, or some similar technique?  The external process is probably associated with a DTS package.

In Windows Task Manager, select Processes and look for an Image Name similar to DTExec.exe or DTExecUI.exe.  If you find one, then select to End Process.  That should kill the process and stop the connections to SQL Server.

When you say "I have restarted the server" are you referring to restarting the computer or stopping and starting the SQL Server service?  Restarting the SQL Server service won't stop this process.

Comment: This is correct, I have yet to find the external task since it is not in my local processes and I did a full os and hardware reboot but it must be an external software trying to get to a non existing database. Thank you for your help.